# golang import - как организован код?

Tags: golang

2 дня в Go
Как там реализовано разделение кода?
Дайте, камрады, простой пример:
абстрактный класс бутыкаПива (в отдельном файле)
светлоеПиво(в отдельном файле)
темноеПиво(в отдельном файле)
Как это все в Go разруливается?
р

Comment: "Марк Саммерфильд - Программирование на языке Go" на рутрекере есть. RTFM!

Answer (score 1):

Вот код для первоначального представления.

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Beer struct {}

func (self Beer) Name() string {
    return "I'm beer"   
}

type LightBeer struct {
    Beer
}

func (self LightBeer) Name() string {
    return "I'm light beer" 
}

type DarkBeer struct {
    Beer
}

func main() {
    a := LightBeer{}
    fmt.Println(a.Name());

    b := DarkBeer{}
    fmt.Println(b.Name());
}
```

Ссылка: https://play.golang.org/p/8RacY6Oc5Y. Вообще понятия абстрактного класса в Go нет, только встраивание (как видно сверху), композиция, агрегирование, а наследование "через интерфейсы".

Советую тоже почитать "Марк Саммерфильд - Программирование на языке Go", Effective Go и FAQ на официальном сайте Golang.

Comment: Вообще вопрос был про, то как принято в golang код по отдельным файлам и пакаджам распределять.

Comment: Если много кода, то лучше в отдельный файл, если немного, то оставляй в том же файле. Создавать файл на каждую структуру, интерфейс и т.д. запаришься из-за большого количества файлов - смысла особого не будет.

Answer (score 1):

Можете попробовать организовать код через структуры. Или же просто красиво и элегантно организуй структуры директорий подобного рода:

```
hello
--src
----common
------newtwork
--------network_type.go
--------network_assign.go
--------network_request.go
------abstract 
--------abstract_common.go
--------abstract_common_xps.go
--main.go
```

Также сделайте группировку пакетов по зависимости. 
Или создавай свои структуры и оттуда их импортируй

```
type User struct {
    ID      int
    Name    string
    Address Address
}

type UserService interface {
    User(id int) (*User, error)
    Users() ([]*User, error)
    CreateUser(u *User) error
    DeleteUser(id int) error
}
```

Также я предпочитаю использовать функции для различного рода действий чтоб код более подходил под стандарты , что-то типа такого:

```
func Hello() {
    fmt.Println("Hello world!")
}

func HttpGet(host string) {
    req, err := http.Get(host)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    } else {
        fmt.Println(req.Body, req.Header)
    }

    defer req.Body.Close()
}
```

И вообще почитайте и загляните сюда - `https://habrahabr.ru/post/308198/`